# Post method a file and string request to spring rest controller that receive byte[] and Strings using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, file, post

How to send a post method that contains a file and another string request parameter to a spring rest controller using angular ?

The server controller parameter receives an array of byte file and other String request which is encapsulated in one entity. I've been working on this for 2 days with no suitable ways for did this.

Here is the image for controller, encapsulated request entity, post method using angular resources, and error from server:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847532/file-upload-in-angularjs-json-spring-mvc-application-400-bad-request-required-re/39851123#39851123 check out this answer by me ! Hope this will give you an understanding

Comment: @Angular_10 Thanks for the answer. maybe i could use that solution, but from now on i'm still looking up for a workaround without changing the server side code and still using ngResource for perform a request method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already done by myself. In javascript i'm converting my file into base64 first, and then convert it into a byte[] in the spring controller using javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary().

Here is the javascript code to manually convert your file into base64 :

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function(ele){
    $scope.files = ele.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        console.log("about to encode");
        $scope.encoded_file = btoa(e.target.result.toString());
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString($scope.files[0]);
    $scope.fileBase64 = new FileReader();
    $scope.fileBase64.readAsDataURL($scope.files[0]);
    console.log("$scope.fileBase64: ",$scope.fileBase64);
};
```

Also set on-change attribute in your file input html like this :

```
<input id="Data" type="file" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFileSelect(this)">
```

In the spring controller itself just change the request file to String that encapsulated in one entity :

```
@RequestBody PositionNew positionNew
```

PositionNew contain attributes :

`private String base64File;
  private String attr1;
  private String attr2;`

That's all.